# AJAX: How to use TWO xmlHttpRequest in parallel in ONE function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

How should I do this?

```
function(id,id2){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
```

> **First Request:**
>
> ```
>    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://example.com/ajax.php?id="+id, true);
>
>    xmlhttp.send();
> ```
>
> **Second Request:**
>
> ```
>    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://example.com/ajax2.php?id2="+id2, true);
>
>    xmlhttp.send();
> ```
>
> }

Because in this way doesn't works.

**I want to make it in plain javascript, so please do not post answers with jQuery or any library etc.**

Thanks

Comment: Use JQuery Ajax. it is simple to use. You will find solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to make it in plain Javascript :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should work if you create a new xmlhttp object. Currently you are attempting to reuse the same object, which is already performing a query so it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for classic javascript style you can use as the following. But use jQuery as it's simple and comprehensive. The one thing to be noted is that the "xmlhr" should be in method (callAjax) scope.

```
function callAjax(url) {
        var xmlhr;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhr.readyState == 4 && xmlhr.status == 200) {
                alert(xmlhr.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhr.send();
    }

    function myFunction(id1, id2) {
        callAjax("http://example.com/ajax2.php?id2=" + id1);
        callAjax("http://example.com/ajax2.php?id2=" + id2);
    }
```

Comment: I had a problem adding event listeners for two (or more) parallel xmlhr objects, but this solution that put each xmlhr object in its own scope made it works. Thank you.